# Powershell script to get list of Running VM's and stop them

Tags: azure, powershell

Am using this script, but its gathering all the vms and stopping it one by one even when the VM is already in stopped state

```
$vm = Get-Azvm 

foreach($vms in $vm)

{
    
    $resource = Get-Azvm | where {$_.Statuses -eq "Running"}

    if($resource -ne $null)
    {  
        Write-Output "Stopping virtual machine..." + $vms
        Stop-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resource.ResourceGroupName -Name $vms -Force
    }   
    else
    {
        Write-output "Virtual machine not found:" + $vms
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `Statuses` is an existing Property of the returned object? By looking at MS Docs seems like you need to use the `-Status` switch so the cmdlet returns that property, in addition, seems like `Satutes` is a nested property i.e. `$vm.Disks[0].Status[0].DisplayStatus`.

Comment: If you're not sure what I meant, try the following, `$vm[0] | Select-Object *` and add the returned object to your question obfuscating information if necessary.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon You are right about `-Status`, but not about `.Statuses`. When passing `-Status`, the cmdlet outputs `PSVirtualMachineInstanceView` which indeed has a `Statuses` [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.compute.models.psvirtualmachineinstanceview?view=az-ps-latest#properties).

Comment: Good to know @zett42, does the object look like [Example 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvm?view=azps-6.6.0#example-2--get-instance-view-properties) when using the switch?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yes, they are using the `-Status` switch there and at the bottom you see the `Statuses` array. I wonder whether `$_.Statuses -eq "Running"` is a valid comparison though. It depends on how `Statuses` converts to string which I don't know.

Comment: @zett42 can you please help me write the correct cmdlet to overcome the issue

Comment: `$vm = Get-AzVM -Name 'OneVMNameHere' -Status` => `$vm.Statuses.GetType()` and `$vm.Statuses | Get-Member`. Both outputs would help us understand how to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the above shared requirement , we have modified the PowerShell script to check the virtual machines status ( whether it is running or not ), if virtual Machine is running you need to stop it using `stop-Azvm` cmdlet.

Checked the below script(while testing we passed resource group flag to the `Get-Azvm` ) in our local environment which is working fine.

```
$vm = Get-Azvm -Status

foreach($vms in $vm)
{
   $statuscheck = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $vms.ResourceGroupName -Name $vms.Name -Status 
    if($statuscheck.Statuses.DisplayStatus[1] -eq "VM running")
    {  

        Write-Output "Stopping virtual machine...$($vms.Name)"

        Stop-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $vms.ResourceGroupName -Name $vms.Name -Force
    }   
    else
    {
        Write-output "Virtual machine $($vms.Name) is already in stopped state"
    }
}
```

Here is the sample output for reference:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this script works absolutely perfect