# How do I parse Kusto Query output into Automation Script (Powershell or Python)

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-automation

I have a Kusto query that will output for me processes from my VMs (whether they are stopped or not).

Here is the query:

```
ConfigurationData 
| project Computer, SvcName, SvcDisplayName, SvcState, TimeGenerated, _ResourceId
| distinct Computer, SvcName, SvcDisplayName, SvcState, TimeGenerated , _ResourceId
| where SvcName =~ "{process_name}" 
| where SvcState != "Running"
```

I need to parse the ComputerName (Computer) to an Automation Script so that it simply turns on the process that is not running.

How can I achieve this?

Would it be wiser to just run the KQL code in the automation script directly? But then, how can I trigger it? It needs to check every 5 mins whether the process is running.  I suppose I could do a scheduling task.

I'm still trying to work at ways of parsing the KQL output to an automation script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is doing with Kusto query, the other way which I do is by using PowerShell commands as below and I followed [SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70149954):

```
$vm = Get-Azvm -Status

foreach($emos in $vm)
{
   $sc = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $emos.ResourceGroupName -Name $emos.Name -Status 
    if($sc.Statuses.DisplayStatus[1] -eq "VM running")
    {
Write-Output "Already started" + $emos
    }
else{
Write-Output "Started now" + $emos
Start-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $emos.ResourceGroupName -Name $emos.Name
}
```

And you can schedule a recurrence in Automation as below after creating the above job in run book as below:

[image]

Or else you can use the above PowerShell Script in Azure PowerShell Functions, after that you can use timer Trigger function.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by fixing the KQL query.

It is not retrieving services that are currently not running, it retrieves services that **in some point in time** were not running.

You should retrieve the last record for each service (running on a specific computer).

```
ConfigurationData 
| where SvcName =~ "{process_name}" 
| project Computer, SvcDisplayName, SvcState, TimeGenerated, _ResourceId
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by Computer
| where SvcState != "Running"
```

Comment: Thanks David, but this query does not produce anything. I have to remove the | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by Computer line for it to work. In any case, I need to parse the computer name and Resource group to an azure automation or azure function. How can I do that?

Comment: The query is fine (as long as you replaced `{process_name}` with your actual *SvcName* name). If you did, that means that all your services are running. I'll let someone else deal with the automation. I'm just trying to save you from doing major mistakes.